# Googlemap is displaying blank grids

Tags: android

I've followed through the code from a tutorial. I registered the sha-1 finger print. then generated the key. Applied it in my code then the rest of the procedure.

Kindly check my codes

**MapsSay.java**

```
   public class MapsSay extends MapActivity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public boolean isRouteDisplayed(){
    return false;

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

   <com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:apiKey="AIzaSyArKRuc5Kba62hRSTMN-dlH_vvuJGKyT28"
    android:clickable="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MapsSay.manifest**

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.say.maps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"> </uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsSay"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you using Google maps API v1?

Comment: Can u check in the google api console . In the services - if Google API for Android is On .

Comment: What is the KeyStore you are using ? Are you running on Device or emulator?

Comment: This looks like Google maps for Android Version 1.

Comment: I'm running this on an emulator.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24437/discussion-between-anukool-and-betty-barnes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's already solved! Thanks to Anukool.

I obtained my key using MD5 not SHA1 because in my code I use  for v1.